# Einstein Bot crashes on random moments

Tags: einstein, bots

I created an Einstein Bot in a trailhead environment and everything went great. Apex calls etc.

Now I'm creating a new bot in the Sandbox Environment of my client and on random moments, the bot tries to send the chat to a live agent. I just don't understand why it doesn't work. Even repeating a simple word makes it crash at different moments in the dialog.

Maybe someone has had the same issue or knows a possible explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: I didn't have the same issue but there's a good way to debug Einstein bots. Under "performances". You should see the exceptions raised.

Comment: Also, most of the problems raised by Einstein bots come from the permission set assigned. When you activate Einstein bots, Salesforce add a new permission set called "sfdc.chatbot.service.permset". Each class called by the bot or each object used must be enable in this permission set.

Comment: Hello Martin. The permission set is configurated and it works, sometimes I get passed the Apex Class, sometimes I don't. But it seems the Chatbot just stops working and in the Performance logs is the following error: [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]